# Power with divide & conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

i want to find for calculating X^46, how many multiplication occurs with optimal D&C approach for calculating Power.

I think this is the best optimal code for calculating power with divide & conquer approach.

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
  {
     int temp;
     if( y == 0)
       return 1;
     temp = power(x, y/2);
     if (y%2 == 0)
       return temp*temp;
     else
       return x*temp*temp;
  }
```

in one note wrote for calculating X^46 with optimal Power code in D&C we need  8 multiplication, but in my code there is 10. anyone correct me?

Edit:

the last code is:

```
  int power(int x, unsigned int y)
  {
     int temp;
     if( y == 0)
       return 1;
     if( y ==1)
        return x;
     temp = power(x, y/2);
     if (y%2 == 0)
       return temp*temp;
     else
       return x*temp*temp;
  }
```

Comment: Where does 8 come from?

Comment: i think you go to deep. why do you need to continue until y==0? stop when y==1 or 2. it can save some multiplications. btw, use `y&0x1==0` instead if you are aware of efficiency.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Repeated squaring, 32+8+4+2=46

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr A decent compiler will make such replacements for you.

Comment: Btw. I don't think this counts as *Divide and Conquer*, just basic recursion.

Comment: @chepner i know. but still, an efficiency-aware programmer should not depend on compiler optimization.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly yes it is. standard D&C to be taught in class.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly-Generally,these are similar and hence commonly exploited to use each intermittently!

Comment: How i should change the code for not going to deep?

Comment: @GeorgSchölly Just because you divide doesn't mean you have to conquer each half individually :)

Comment: @AIismylove chepner is correct. try to implement in his way.

Comment: Are you by any change following a book on algorithms? What is its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You left out the optimizing base case of

```
 if (y==1)
     return x
```

and instead require extra multiplications from

```
 temp = power(x, 0)
 return x * temp * temp
```

The extra pair of multiplications come from the unnecessary final recursive call.

Comment: Dear Chepener, would you please more explain ?

Comment: When `y==1`, you can return `x` immediately since `x^1 == x` for all `x`. You don't need to first compute `x^0` recursively, then return `x * 1 * 1`.

Comment: would you please change my code and add into your answer?

Comment: You just need to add another base case to your function.

Answer (score 2):

You have redundant multiplies due to not earlying out when `y==1`.

When `y==1`, you execute the last line:

```
return x*temp*temp;
```

which simplifies to:

```
return x*1*1;
```

Adding a special case for `y==1` will get rid of the additional 2 multiplies.

Answer (score 0):

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
  {
     int temp;
     if( y ==1)
        return x;

     if (y%2 == 0){
      temp = power(x, y/2);
       return temp*temp;
     }
     else{
       temp = power(x, (y-1)/2);
       return x*temp*temp;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it using the divide and conquer strategy. it will take O(log N) time to complete the execution. It will work for negative exponential also.

I'm doing this in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float power(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        float temp = power(a, b / 2);
        if (b > 0)
        {
            if (b % 2 == 0)
            {
                return temp * temp;
            }
            else
            {
                return a * temp * temp;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 1/power(a,-b);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{       int a , b ;
        cout<<"Enter a Number:";cin>>a; cout<<"Enter its exponential:";cin>>b;
        cout << power(a, b);
}
```

Output:

[Output will be as follow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQps.png)